# codeigniter controllers not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I am new to web development, so this problem may be very simple.

I have xampp installed and running, and am using netbeans latest version.

I'm currently trying to follow a tutorial which requires me to make a couple controllers, yet the only page I can successfully load is index.php.

I have made a new controller in application/controllers folder:

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Say something';
    }
}
?>
```

And tried to access it via

```
http://localhost/Something/Blog
```

But I get an error:

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3
```

p.s.

```
http://localhost/Something is loading fine.
```

And I've edited the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ." index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I have been googling for the solution for 3 hours, I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: try this : http://localhost/Something/index.php/controllername

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change .htaccess file to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also, try accessing with:

```
http://localhost/Something/index.php/Blog
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

localhost/Something/index.php/controllername

Answer (score 0):

Also write name of `controller class` and `method` in small in browser url. you can access using:

```
http://localhost/index.php/something/blog
```

Answer (score 0):

Add htaccess this code my help

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```